# flutter: sqflite insert error, "datatype mismatch"

Tags: sql, database, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

The CREATE successfully works, but INSERT doesn't work. I think arguments of INSERT are correct... but why?

(09.09 modify) The problem is the category problem with string input argument.

Docker) INSERT INTO Quest(category) VALUES(?) args[walking(X) / ‘walking’(O) / “walking”(O)]

Flutter) INSERT INTO Quest(category) VALUES(?) args[walking(X) / ‘walking’(X) / “walking”(X)]

```
flutter: CREATE TABLE Quest ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    category TEXT, 
    level INTEGER, 
    need_token INTEGER, 
    reward_token INTEGER,
    start_date TIMESTAMP, 
    finish_date TIMESTAMP, 
    achieve_date TIMESTAMP, 
    goal INTEGER, 
    need_times INTEGER, 
    achievement INTEGER
)

flutter: DatabaseException(
    Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=20 "datatype mismatch" 
    UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=datatype mismatch}
) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Quest (
    category, 
    level, 
    need_token, 
    reward_token, 
    start_date, 
    finish_date, 
    achieve_date, 
    goal, need_times, 
    achievement
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, ?, ?, ?)' 
args ['walking', 0, 0, 1, 1662658696748, 1662745096748, 100, 1, 0]
```

However, the INSERT SQL works in sqlite of docker.

[sqlite in docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kZYv.png)

In docker, the SQL successfully works but not with sqflite, Flutter. What should I do?

The class of Quest is here.

```dart
class Quest {
  String category;
  int level;
  int needToken;
  int rewardToken;
  DateTime startDate;
  DateTime finishDate;
  DateTime? achieveDate;
  int goal;
  int needTimes;
  int achievement;

  ...

  Map<String, dynamic> toDBData() => {
    'category': "'$category'",
    'level': level,
    'need_token': needToken,
    'reward_token': rewardToken,
    'start_date': startDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    'finish_date': finishDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    'achieve_date': achieveDate?.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    'goal': goal,
    'need_times': needTimes,
    'achievement': achievement
  };
}
```

```dart
Future<void> insertQuest(Quest quest) async =>
      await dbHelper.insert(_tableName, quest.toDBData());
```

```dart
Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, dynamic> data) async => await db!
            .insert(table, data, conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
```

Please help me... I struggled this problem for days but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: while I have no knowledge of flutter/sqlite, I think your VALUES and args dont match in terms of number of arguments. Why dont you pass null in args instead of putting it as part of VALUES? OR dont include the column for which you want to insert null value?

Comment: Thanks you! However the NULL argument of the achieveData column is correct. The problem is the category column with string input argument.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem by

```dart
db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
          onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db
            .execute(statement..trim().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\s]{2,}'), ' '));
      }, 
          // add 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE' SQL to onOpen function.
          onOpen: (Database db) async {
        // await db.execute("DROP TABLE $tableName);
        await db
            .execute(statement..trim().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\s]{2,}'), ' '));
      });
```

The problem is the Quest table is already created, but attributes isn't same as what I wanna create. So I drop and recreate it.